# Tor StrictExitNodes is not working

Tags: tor

So, following advice from all over the Internet, including Tor documentation, I'm trying to force US-only exit nodes by editing the torrc file like so:

```
StrictNodes 1
ExitNodes {US}
```

But, I’m still getting exit nodes from Western Europe, Australia, and the US. I’m using the Vidalia bundle, though I’m starting Tor and Polipo from the command line programmatically and executing HttpWebRequests via Polipo. Any thoughts? I really, really need the exit nodes to only be from the US, and I'm really surprised this isn't working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I appear to have fixed the problem by adding this argument when I start Tor from the command line:

```
-f C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Vidalia\torrc
```

I'm not sure why Tor wasn't using this config file by default, but now that I'm pointing to it explicitly, it appears to be following the StrictNodes directive. Thanks.